# How can I restart mongodb with --auth option in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: mongodb

Well, restarting works with stop and start command, but I cannot seem to execute the mongodb command with --auth option.

```
root@random:/home/random/public_html# mongodb stop
root@random:/home/random/public_html# start mongodb --auth
start: invalid option: --auth
root@random:/home/random/public_html# start mongodb
mongodb start/running, process 29473
root@random:/home/random/public_html#
```

How can I start mongodb with --auth option?

Comment: I installed it as apt-get mongodb package, which gave me configuration file in /etc/mongodb.conf . I edited that file to set nohttpinterface=true, and I think that did it all...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and add a line like this:

```
auth=true
```

Then:

```
service mongod restart
```

See this page for more configuration options: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration

**For MongoDB latest versions 3.x above code wont work, below code in mongod.conf if you are using mongodb 3.x**

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

Comment: Need quotes around "enabled" for 4.x

Comment: Do you know what will work for windows? I have tried all these with no luck.

Comment: For MongoDB 3.x  => sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf          then enable auth=true

Answer (score 60):

If you are using MongoDB 3, setting `auth = true` wont work. You will instead need the following in your /etc/mongod.conf

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 17):

For mongodb version 3.2

this is the correct config

```
security:
   authorization: "enabled"
```

in String format

Comment: Correct answer for 3.2 version

Comment: Correct answer for 4.0

Comment: Correct for 5.0 ,followed by `sudo service mongod restart`

Answer (score 5):

Just want to supplement the answer. For MongoDB 3, the /etc/mongod.conf has changed. Either of below enable MondgoDB authorization option (--auth):

security:
   keyFile: [The path to a key file]

-- or--

security:
   authorization: enabled

[Details can be found here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options)

Answer (score 0):

you should put the `--auth` option in the startup script

```
/etc/rc[0-6].d/mongod
```

Comment: I see 7 folders rc0,rc1...rc6 in /etc/ directory. I do not understand that part. Do you mean I have to start it by /etc/init.d/mongod --auth ?? I get the following error if I do that. "The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but --auth is not supported for Upstart jobs.
"

Comment: Don't do it this way (by editing the init/upstart script), that is why there is a /etc/mongodb.conf file.

Comment: yup, /etc/mongodb.conf is much better place